# Schedule google cloud function (no triggers)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So I have a very simple python script that writes a txt-file to my google storage bucket.
I just want to set this job to run each hour i.e not based on a trigger. It seems like that when using SDK, it needs to have a --triger- flag, but I only want it to be "triggered" by the scheduler.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Cloud Function with Pub/Sub trigger and then create a Cloud Scheduler job targeting the topic which triggers the function.

I did it by following these steps:

> 1. Create a Cloud Function with Pub/Sub trigger
> 2. Select your topic or create a new one
> 3. This is the default code I am using:

```
exports.helloPubSub = (event, context) => {
  const message = event.data
    ? Buffer.from(event.data, 'base64').toString()
    : 'Hello, World';
  console.log(message);
};
```

> 4. Create a Scheduler job targeting with the same Pub/Sub topic
> 5. Check it is working.

I tried it with the frequency `*****` **(every minute)** and it works for me, I can see the logs from the Cloud Function.

Currently in order to execute a Cloud Function it needs to be [triggered](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling) because once it stops the execution the only way to execute it again is through the trigger.

You can also follow the same steps I indicated to you in [this page](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/4975/how-to-run-gcp-cloud-functions-periodically-with-cloud-scheduler/) where you can find some images for further help.